# How to properly freeze cake

Tags: freezing, cake

I have a cake project coming up and have to bake a few different cakes. I'm not much of a baker and was anticipating having to bake all of these at roughly the same time. I was thinking that I could save some time on the day I need to actually prepare the cake by baking the cakes ahead of time and freezing them so I don't have to prepare the batter, bake, cool, and then decorate all in the same day.

First off, what are the adverse affects of freezing a cake?

How should one go about preparing a cake in order to freeze it and minimize any damage?

When I say cake I am talking about unfrosted cake layers.

Comment: See also: [Where should I store my cakes?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/29636/15003)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most cakes will freeze and keep fine if prepared properly - obviously they will not have the same "fresh baked" attributes that a freshly baked cake would bring to the party, but it should still taste nicely.

1. Wait for the cake(s) to be completely cooled before preparing them to be frozen.
2. Use one of the following methods/materials to wrap the room temperature cake before placing in the freezer:

   - greaseproof paper (wax paper, for example), wrapped thoroughly around the cake and taped shut
   - aluminum foil with plastic wrap/greaseproof paper underneath it, thoroughly secured
   - vacuum seal bag (caution: too much pressure may cause the cake to loose it's shape)
3. To thaw: Unwrap the cake, place it on a wire rack in your kitchen and let it sit for about two hours (more/less time depending on size of the cake) at normal room temperature. It is important that you *do not* microwave or reheat a frozen cake in any way, or you will ruin it.

More details are available here: http://www.wikihow.com/Freeze-Cakes

Comment: wikihow is not a good source or information. They are scrapped (usually via slave wages) answers

Answer (score 1):

Different cakes freeze better or worse than others, it completely depends on the cake. But freezing might be unnecessary altogether. Most cakes are better not frozen if it's only going to be frozen for shorter than the times below.

Heavy Fruit cakes with alcohol can be made well ahead of time, un-iced over 6 months, ice a week or so before serving! Lighter fruit cakes can be made 3-5 days in advance (the more fruit the longer on that scale but 3 is pretty safe) and can usually be stored iced. Bread cakes (like banana bread) will last 3 days. Sponge/cupcakes/pound cake are best within 2-3 days and iced as late as you have time to. Cream can only really be added on the day as cake isn't great in the refrigerator.

To store cakes for maximum freshness wrap in greaseproof paper un-iced and if storing fresh wrap in cling-film over this and keep in a cake tin or other air tight container. If you are freezing the cake put tinfoil or a freezer bag over the cling-film and ice while frozen or defrost still wrapped.