# Where should I store my cakes?

Tags: storage-method, cake, freezing

Where is the best place to store cakes?

I usually store them in a normal, plastic box but I had  an idea to store them in a freezer. Would that be okay to store cakes there? Could it degrade the flavour and the taste?

I'm asking because I don't want to throw away cakes which are both chocolate and ribbon, if that matters.

Comment: see also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14016/how-to-properly-freeze-cake

Comment: Thanks @rumtscho that is a much better answer you linked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most cakes freeze extremely well--especially cakes that are not iced, such as bundt cakes.

Wrap the cake in plastic wrap, then aluminum foil, and freeze.  For cupcakes or slices, you can put them in a freezer bag.

If you are going to freeze a whole cake, it is better to frost it after thawing, as the icing can be tricky.

If you have icing, you can put the cake in the freezer long enough for the icing to br firm, and then wrap and freeze--however, thawing can be tricky as you might get a bit of condensation, which can affect the texture of the frosting.

EDIT in response to question about a plastic box, and why the double layering:

1. Boxes consume space extra space, often at a premium in a freezer, and offer air gaps in which freezer burn is more likely.
2. Not all plastic is food-safe.
3. The food-safe plastic wrap is for direct contact with the cake but is gas permeable.  I suppose you could just go directly to foil, but things are more likely to stick to it.
4. The foil provides a gas and moisture barrier (and light, but that is less of a problem in the freezer).
5. The direct contact with the with the cake eliminates the air gaps, making freezer burn much less likely.

Comment: Wouldn't an air tight plastic bag or plastic box be better than plastic wrap and aluminium foil? What purpose doe that aluminium foil perform?

Comment: @TFD See edit in answer, as it was too much to address in a comment.

Comment: Sorry, load of rubbish SAJ, any domestic plastic packaging is food safe. Some plastic may not be ideal when heated, but that is fuzzy science still

Comment: How will plastic wrap make an airtight layer? It can be air tight over a smooth glass bowl, but not over a crumbly cake! Use a closable plastic bag and vacuum it if worried about a little freezer burn (unlikely if only a small gap). Foil will not provide a seal, unless glued closed. Freezer burn is the result of changing dry air every time the freezer door is opened

Comment: @Tfd I never said the plastic is air tight--in fact, it is gas permeable.  You asked why this method, I answered.  Is it perfect?  No.  Is it the only possible method?  No.  Is it the method of choice you will find if you google the question?  Yes.  Is it effective?  Yes.   Please go ahead and provide another answer with a another perspective if you feel strongly.   And please address the ideas, but saying "load of rubbish" borders on personal and adds no value.  Your point would have been just as clear if you left that part out, or simply said "I strongly disagree".