# Change cake recipe (or technique) to improve consistency after freezing

Tags: baking, freezing

I'm interested in how I can improve a recipe for better freezing capabilities. For freezing I follow pretty much [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14016/how-to-properly-freeze-cake?noredirect=1&lq=1). The cake however still lacks a lot of "fluffyness" compared to the unfrozen recipe.
I make this cake by filling a form with the frosting and putting the baked cake into the form after. The complete form gets wrapped in airtight foil and frozen. After freezing i remove the form and defrost the cake. The main reason for the freezing is to create a specific form of the frosting by the mold inspired by the work of [Dinara Kasko's work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qBZSTOUz_8).

I'm interested in how I can improve either my method or the recipe. I was thinking about adding layer between cake and frosting that is low in water content. However I don't know if the cake draws much water from the frosting as it is rich in fat/ chocolate and therefore seals the cake already. Adding ingredients would be another idea however I wouldn't know what I need.

I'm really interested into the food chemistry or what i can do to maintain the consistency. While the answer in the other post gives great advice it is relatively unspecific in reference to my question.

Thanks for any help in advance!

The ingredients are:

Cake

- 150g flour
- 100g ground almonds
- 25g cacao powder
- 2 tsp baking powder
- 1 tsp salt
- 150g coconut oil
- 250ml maple syrup
- 1tsp vanilla extract
- 100ml rice milk

Frosting:

- 200g dark chocolate pellets
- 150ml water

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jQxzsooDdQ)

Comment: How do you defrost the cake? I ask because this can affect the texture as much as freezing in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried defrosting it at room temperature or in a container in the fridge however I wasn't happy with both. The cake still is great but not fluffy at all :-)

Comment: Hi John Miller, it is indeed unpleasant to close a question into which somebody put so much effort. I marked it as a duplicate because, as far as I can see, the other answers do cover your case. First, you are freezing the frosted cake, and the answers already tell you that you cannot freeze frosting. Second, if your layers also don't come out well after freezing, then this is also expected to some extent, but if they are really bad, there is nothing you can do except to stop freezing this cake and only use other recipes when you need to freeze the layers.

Comment: Hi rumtscho, I really do not see how the other question answers my post. In the other answers there is one general remark that "you can't add cream" that sounds rather like an opinion than proven truth. In fact the frosting in the recipe mentioned by me comes out great, the cake also is not _bad_, in fact I get complimented on it a lot. It is just not as good as I think it could get.

Comment: There is a complete scientific field on how to apply the slightest changes to recipe or techniques, books like Modernist Cuisine go into great detail to really show how the smallest things can have a significant impact, yet one paragraph on this site when it comes to freezing a cake is all there ever will be? In other fields stack exchange is really the go to address for in depth advice from top in their field participants. Even this site claims to be for "professional and amateur cooks and chefs" but anything that goes beyond mundane kitchen knowledge doesn't have a chance of discussion?

Comment: And a regurgitated wikihow answer at that.

Comment: I've now had the chance to look into Modernist Cuisine which has a great segment on this topic. It does explain what actually happens and why. I now have a few pointers and things I'll try next time I make this recipe and won't waste more time on this page. Which is really a shame as stackexchange usually is a great way to spread knowledge.

Comment: If the issue is the cake sucking moisture from the frosting, you might be able to freeze the frosting, then insert the cake (with a crumb coat so it still has something to adhere the two together)…. But I suspect that the issue is that some starches change when cooled… it’s why long grain rice is firmer and less sticky after being in the fridge, even after you warm it back up

Comment: I edited it to provide more information about the reason for freezing. I'm not really sure if the cake is sucking moisture from the frosting, I'm just wondering if it could. However what I found out so far is that a lot of the negative side effects of freezing are due to ice crystals forming in the material. Freezing it faster can potentially help with limiting the size of the crystals. My next try will be to freeze the cake first before putting it into the frosting and also freezing it bagged in an salt-ice-bath to freeze it faster.

Comment: Smaller sizes should also help for faster freezing. Ultimately liquid nitrogen should do a great job but that's maybe a bit too much for me to consider it at the moment ;-) However I'm still interested in a definite answer if it could take up moisture from the frosting or not.

Comment: Any chance you could mock-up a diagram of what you mean by form with the frosting and cake? As it is, there could be a number of things that might alter how the cake freezes. Ice crystals is certainly a problem for texture - you could try a frost-free freezer or a sealed container to prevent moisture getting in.  Seal between frosting and cake - could use ganache or melted chocolate.

Comment: Good point, I've added [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qBZSTOUz_8) showing the process to the description.

Answer (score 1):

### Why are you losing the fluffiness

Your cake is going stale. The word may surprise you when used here, because people associate "stale" with "old" - but what creates staleness is not time, but physical changes on the microscopic level. And if you freeze a cake, you automatically get these changes.

The main problem is not too-large-ice-crystals, but starch retrogradation. The flour and the cocoa powder in your cake contain raw starch - long polymer molecules tightly packed in granules. When you make your batter, you hydrate the starch (water goes into the granules and binds loosely to the starch) and when you bake it, starch gelatinization occurs - the starch granules burst, and the mixture of free starch molecules and water makes an unordered (=soft) gel. But both starch and water prefer to form ordered, crystalline structures. So starch chains replace their loose bonds to water with slightly stronger bonds to other starch chains, precipitating out of the gel - that is retrogradation.

This process occurs naturally over a few days through brownian motion. But the moment you freeze something, you force it to pack tightly - and give it a very good incentive to get as ordered as it can. So, **freezing itself automatically creates an unavoidable, irreversible loss of fluffiness.**

This is the main effect you are observing. Other ones can also happen, such as condensation during thawing, or freezer burn, but I don't think they are especially pronounced in your case.

### Ideas that won't work

The thought about quick freezing is, at first glance, not so bad. But its main effect is on the size of ice crystals in the water phase, which is important for vegetables or ice cream, but not the main contributor to quality loss in frozen cake. The second problem is that you cannot achieve a quick enough cooling down at home to make a noticeable difference. And third, since you cannot chill it rapidly, you probably plan to keep it chilled at almost 0°C before freezing. Only, I glossed over a ton of information about starch retrogradation in the previous section. One is that starch produces different crystals depending on the conditions under which it retrogrades, and keeping it at fridge temperature produces the hardest, most unpleasant crystals which give the stalest texture.

Making a barrier between the layer and the frosting is also not going to make the cake fluffier. Its problem is that it is losing moisture, not that it is sucking it - and it is using it on a scale where you cannot physically intervene.

### What you can do instead

Having established that having the cake stay the same would require you to break the second law of thermodynamics, let's look at ways to cheat.

1. Don't freeze the cake

These sculpted mold works are usually made with frosting with some structural stability to it. If you make a smaller cake layer part and thicker frosting, you will probably be able to freeze a thick "shell" out of the frosting and place the cake into it after it comes out of the freezer. I expect that it will need experimentation before it works properly - you probably should freeze a placeholder shaped exactly the cake layer, and then still have some gaps to fill with fresh frosting when combining, which will make your cake somewhat prone to separation. But it feels doable.

Or alternatively, pack the cake bottom with some insulation, and only keep it in the freezer for the minimum of time to get the frosting hard enough to unmold, without having the cake (or most of it) freeze. It will be hard to pull off, but not impossible.

2. Do not bake a fluffy cake

If your cake is losing its appeal because it was mostly based on fluffiness, switch to baking a cake whose appeal is not based on being very fluffy. You have different ways to go there. You can try to make your cake more moist and dense, taking it into the direction of brownies. If you want to reengineer the existing recipe to achieve that, some avenues for experimentation would be to stop using almonds, to start using chocolate instead of cocoa powder, to add egg yolks, to increase the amount of fat, to use additives (lecithine and other fatty-teture-imitating ones would be likely candidates) to use a different liquid (cream, sour cream, or apple butter) instead of the rice milk, to reduce the liquid, and to make changes to the sweetener - use more of it, and something with more fructose content than maple syrup, but preferably less moisture (so powdered fructose would be better than corn syrup). As usual when reengineering a cake recipe, don't make more than one change at once, and keep a detailed experiment log for each attempt, or you'll get quite lost.

You can also make a cake that is dry on purpose, going for a genoise or savoiardi style layer or a joconde one (since you are into visuals, you can hide the classic stripes on the inside, that would be fun!). A dacquoise might be an interesting choice, but I don't know how it would react to thawing, especially when embedded in frosting. Or make a recipe which is fluffy when baked, but still tastes good when dried, like some commercial cake bars, because of the very fine, well-dispersed aeration.

3. Mask the dryness

You can always syrup your cake. It is a classic technique that not only makes the drying out irrelevant, but also allows you to adjust taste (sweetness) and aroma.

Other options are to make a fine-layered cake, like a Prinzregententorte. Or make the layer out of a cake pop mass or some other form of processed sponge, where you can incorporate moisture and fat.

### Conclusion (or TL; DR)

You aren't doing anything wrong. The loss of fluffiness is normal, and unavoidable. As the answers in [our general cake-freezing question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14016/how-to-properly-freeze-cake?noredirect=1&lq=1) state, "Different cakes freeze better or worse than others" and "they will not have the same "fresh baked" attributes that a freshly baked cake would", and this is exactly what is happening here. All you can do is to follow the standard cake-freezing advice (wrap it properly, don't let it thaw and freeze repeatedly) which will save you from further problems like freezer burn, but not from loss of fluffiness. If you absolutely insist, you can choose a different recipe where the fluffiness loss is not relevant - but of course that won't be the same cake.

Comment: @JohnMiller I came across this question again, and nobody else has weighed in. I sadly don't have any better news for you than the first time I read the question, but after I saw the long comment thread, I got the feeling that you might be interested in the long explanation, so I wrote it up, hoping it clarifies things.

Comment: Hey, thanks, this is really great and more what I look for than the one on WikiHow, at least this gives me a better understanding on the process. I tried to compare the results with  slow freezing and quick freezing and I could not find. I didn't find noticeable differences for both methods which is in agreement with your explanation. However my "quick" method was done with an ice/salt water bath so faster than freezer yet not instant at all.

Comment: I also like the idea with using something else for the molding stage, however I don't think this will work well. As you can see in the video above there is quite some force needed when removing the mold, so an unfrozen middle would probably result in a broken cake. Leaving an insert in the cake while removing the mold might work, however a lot of handling including turning would be required afterwards which includes the risk of the frosting to start melting. I'll probably give you the answer but I want to think about this and try a bit more. Especially as I now know better on what to look for.

Comment: downvoted, as no one of the three suggestion is relevant to the question

Comment: @argos what have been a more useful way to answer a question for which no solutions exist?